# No module definition file specified

Tags: c, turbo-c

So i have this code, the snippet is given below.

```
list* init(list* list1)
{
  list1->head = NULL;
  list1->size = 0;
  return list1;
}
```

list1 is a linked list and init is called from main function.
now on the line `list1->head= NULL`, after i run the code it highlights this particular line and says

No module definition file specified: using defaults.

and it stopd execution.

I am using turbo C on windows 7.

what shall i do?
Shall i post the complete code.. It is kinda big though..

Comment: Could you please add assert(list1); in the top of the function.

Comment: I suspect we'll need more code to figure it out. That being said, it's possible that NULL is not defined for your compiler - try `list1->head = 0` and see if it complains.

Comment: @Chris on changing it to `list->head =0` it says,
General Protection Exception 
0x213F:0X000D Processor fault

Comment: @eisbaw 

    list* init(list* list1)
    {
    assert(list1) ;

      list1->head = NULL;
      list1->size = 0;
      return list1;
    }

on running gives assertion failed. Probable reasons?

Comment: @Karan if `assert(list1)` failed, that means that you didn't allocate memory for list1 before calling the function. Do you have a `list* list1 = malloc(sizeof(list))` somewhere before this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments it looks like a combination of factors.

First, it appears the Turbo C compiler doesn't know what NULL is. Since NULL is just a typedef for 0, you can use 0 instead.

Second, it seems you haven't allocated memory for the list object. Try doing the following before you call the function.

```
list* list1 = malloc(sizeof(list));
```

However, if what you're trying to do is create and initialize a new `list` object, you're better off rewriting the function as follows:

```
list* init(){
    list *new_list = malloc(sizeof(list));
    new_list->head = 0; // <-- this sets head to the equivalent of NULL
    new_list->size =0;
    return new_list;
}
```

If what you want is a function that *reinitializes* an existing list, then you're causing a memory leak with your current code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is defined in < stddef.h > for C, and the equivalent < cstddef > for C++.